# How to change active color of materialize icon?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm doing a web app for a school project and I'm using materialize for it but I can't change the default teal color of the icon when it's active
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax, It's just a sample change it with your style

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Materialize adds `.active` class to icon, when input is active.

```css
i.material-icons.prefix.active {
    color: #1e469a;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Keep in mind, this code changes color of all icons, that are placed before the input in your project.